# Form data disappear after refresh in php

Tags: php, html

Hi I am new to `PHP` and here I am developing a mulit page form, but as soon as page is refreshed, entered data is disappeared, below code is I am writing.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    echo $_POST['name'].'<br/>';
}
?>


<form method="POST" action="">
<p>NAME</p>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php 
                                      if(isset($_POST['name'])){
                                          echo htmlentities ($_POST['name']);
                                      } 
                                      ?>" /> 
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="keep value" name="submit"/> <br/>

</form>
```

Comment: what;s your actual question? What are you **exactly** expecting? What do you **exactly** want?

Comment: If you mean the user reloading the current page in their browser - in case the current page _was_ the result of a POST request already, their browser usually asks them, if they want to send the same data again. If that’s not the case you are talking about - then explain what you actually mean by “refresh”.

Comment: @treyBake I am developing a form, but I need eventhough page is refreshed, entered data should remain

Comment: @P.S.F.Romesh `eventhough` <- what is?

Comment: my guess is, (though not sure on the question itself), you want to make use of `$_SESSION` **and** `$_POST`

Comment: @treyBake,  I have a form with user to fill details. but while filling the form, if page is refreshed, then already entered data in form is disapper and user need to fill it from first

Comment: @treyBake , I think you got my point, I dont know how to add code using $_SESSION and $_POST

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code like this.

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name']; // After form submit store value in $name variable to keep this value in input box
    echo $_POST['name'].'<br/>';
}else{
    $name = ""; // Store empty value if the form is not submit 
} ?>

<form method="POST" action="">
<p>NAME</p>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php $name; ?>" /> 
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="keep value" name="submit"/> <br/>
```

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard , OK

Comment: This will throw an undefined variable error `value="<?php $name; ?>"`.

Comment: @ Funk Forty Niner, No chance of getting an error, because there is if..else statement, So any one of the condition will be definitely true. Meaning that if the condition is 1) True, $name value is a posted input value. 2) If the condition is False $name value is empty.